# Не получается отобразить значение переменной на экране устройства. SWIFT

Tags: swift

У меня не удается отобразить значение переменной на экране устройства, что я делаю не верно?
У меня есть структура, у которой помимо прочих есть свойство "price". В этой же области видимости я создаю **отдельную** переменную "totalBalance"

```
struct Item {
var price: Int

init(price: Int) {
    self.price = price
}}

    var totalBalance = 0.00
```

Как я понимаю и структура и переменная находятся в максимально доступной области видимости приложения, это важный момент. Именно с переменной "totalBalance" у меня в дальнейшем возникнет проблема отображения.

Далее я создаю массив способный принимать в себя структуры по типу той, которую я создал выше:

```
var items = [Item]()
```

Наполняю я этот массив структурами при помощи делегирования с отдельной специальной страницы приложения создавая новый экземпляр структуры:

```
@IBAction func saveCklicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let price = Int(expencePriceTextField.text ?? " ") ?? 0
    }
    
    let newItem = Item(price: price)

    delegate?.addItemToArrey(self, didAddItem: newItem)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

После чего уже этот, новый экземпляр, помещаю в массив:

```
func addItemToArrey(_ addExpences: AddExpences, didAddItem item: Item) {
    items.append(item)
    tableViewApp.reloadData()

    totalBalance += Double(item.price)    
    print((totalBalance))   
}
```

При добавлении в массив нового экземпляра структуры, я также меняю значение переменной "totalBalance" прибавляя к ней значение параметра "price" каждого нового экземпляра структуры при добавлении его в массив.
До этого момента все работает исправно: массив наполняется, значение "totalBalance" увеличивается на значение параметра "price" с каждым новым элементом в массиве.

А вот теперь я хочу отобразить на мониторе устройства этот самый параметр "totalBalance". Для этого я создаю аутлет лейбла:

```
@IBOutlet private var balanceLabel: UILabel!
```

И при помощи функции хочу в его значение поместить подпись и значение параметра "totalBalance":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    balanceConfig()


private func balanceConfig() {
    
    balanceLabel.text = "Balance = \(totalBalance)"
    print(totalBalance)   
}}
```

Вот тут то все и перестает работать, как я хочу: сколько бы экземпляров я не добавил массив, какое бы значение не имел параметр "totalBalance" (при условии, что оно точно больше нуля), лейбл стабильно отображает надпись "Balance = 0.0".

При команде "print(totalBalance)" внутри этой же функции консоль стабильно выдает ноль.
В моем понимании переменную "totalBalance" видно из любой зоны видимости программы, это подтверждается тем, что при команде принт из других точек программы консоль показывает действительное значение переменной. Но вот в функцию balanceConfig() мне это зачине передать правильно почему то не удается, хотя эта функция в моем понимании способна "видеть" эту переменную и правильное её значение.

Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не верно, как мне отобразить значение переменной в этот аутлет?
Благодарю!

Comment: Приведите более развернутый пример, непонятно где вы изменяете значение totalBalance и где вызываете balanceConfig

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ваш совет, пересоздал вопрос полностью расписав код, что и как делаю
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432169/Не-удается-отобразить-значение-переменной-на-экране-устройства-через-аутлет-swi

Comment: Вместо этого лучше делать правки в текущем вопросе

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Хотел вставить код с viewWillAppear, но что-то или я или сайт глючит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень всё понял, но думаю, что понял из-за чего не отображается.

Во первых зачем ваша функция balanceConfig находится во viewDidLoad?
Вытащите ее оттуда наружу.

Во вторых и это самое главное. Вам нужно изучить жизненный цикл методов UIViewController, потому что метод viewDidLoad() вызывается только один раз при старте отображения вью контроллера (даже когда он еще не отображен на экране) и соотвественно ваша функция balanceConfig() также вызывается только один раз в САМОМ начале. Я правда могу ошибаться, так как вы там что-то пишите про отдельный экран для добавления.

В любом случает я вижу 2 варианта решения (только оба на догадках, так как не видно всего кода):

1. Вам нужно вызывать метод balanceConfig() где-то после того как добавляется новый item в массив. ВОЗМОЖНО в конце вашего @IBAction func saveCklicked().
2. Или (тут только мои догадки), если у вас открывается какой-то другой экран для добавления, а потом он закрывается и опять появляется этот ваш текущий вью контроллер, и вы хотите, чтобы при возвращении на него обновился лэйбл, то можно, например добавить метод viewWillAppear() или viewDidAppear() (любой один из этих), в котором и вызывать вашу функцию обновления.

Пока такие предложения :)

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы, с функцией все ок, вставил её после добавления экземпляра структуры и все начало отображаться! Теперь не могу понять зачем вообще тлил эту функцию во вью дидактиков лад... Жизненный цикл это да контроллера, тут у меня пробел, буду заниматься, спасибо!